# Core Data faulting in NSArray

Tags: cocoa, core-data, automatic-ref-counting, nsfetchrequest, xmppframework

I have a method that performs a NSFetchRequest to obtain an array of managed objects (specifically XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObjects). The objects fault correctly before the array is returned by the performUserFetch and I can print all the displayNames, but once I return the array to printUserInfo, the objects enter a fault state, which wouldn't be a problem except Core Data won't bring them back!

```
- (NSArray*)performUserFetch 
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[xmppRosterStorage persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    [context setUndoManager:nil];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, sd2, nil];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSError *err;

    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];
    return result;

}

- (void)printUserInfo 
{
    NSArray *result = [self performUserFetch];
    for(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user in result)
    {
        NSString *dn = user.displayName;
        NSLog(@"Display name = %@", dn);
    }
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
```

I call printUserInfo every 5 seconds, and the result array if fine in performUserFetch, but everything's gone to pot in printUserInfo, and all the elements in the array have been purged from memory. That would be fine, but when I call user.displayName the fault isn't resolved, so dn has a value of null, and the description of the user is

```
"<XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject: 0x10219fd60> (entity: XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject; id: 0x1021a3390 <x-coredata://324B9E93-BAD1-42B4-B7DB-2A62CA69BA13/XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject/p127> ; data: <fault>)"
```

Can anyone help?!

(Info: 10.7 SDK, printUserInfo is called every 5 seconds, and is running under ARC)

Comment: Just curious, I'm running into the exact same problem.  Did you ever solve this?

Comment: You should select Mundi's answer as the answer

Answer (score 5):

Just guessing. It would be promising to try the following

1. Don't recreate a managed object context each time. Keep it as a property of your class.
2. Maybe you should also alloc/init the array to be sure the memory stays allocated. You could also use a property.

<strike>An alternative solution, BTW, is to use an `NSFetchedResultsController`. It has been designed to be particularly reliable and efficient when it comes to faulting.</strike>

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController doesn't exist in Cocoa, only in Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Mundi, thank you so much! Your solution number 1 saved my day, I was going **crazy**, and now I understand I need to keep the MOC as a property of my class.

Answer (score 2):

Managed objects don't automatically retain their context. When `-performUserFetch` returns and `context` goes out of scope, your managed object context is garbage collected. Without the context, the managed objects themselves are useless.

Retain the context yourself somewhere (as Mundi also suggested) for as long as you need to use those `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject` instances.